# In Maven, when does a project become part of the reactor?

Tags: java, maven, versions-maven-plugin

I was just reading the source code for the [Versions Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/), and noticed this snippet of code:

```
   if ( reactorProjects.contains( getProject().getParent() ) )
   {
       getLog().info( "Project's parent is part of the reactor" );
       return;
   }
```

In general, when does a project (or the parent of a project) become part of the reactor and what are the implications of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question on the Maven mailing list as well. Looks like by default the parent project is always a part of the reactor. However, by passing some options to Maven it might be excluded from the reactor during a build, such as:

- When you use `-pl` to restrict the reactor
- when you use `-f` to build a specific pom